# Detect UITableViewCell Click in custom Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableViewController with some static cells embedded into an UIViewController using a container view. Within this UITableViewController I need the possibility to toggle the visibility of a cell containing an UIPickerView. I tried the following within my TableViewController to detect a tap on the cell but it didn't print anything:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Tap detected.", didSelectRowAtIndexPath)
}
```

I also tried working with reuse identifiers but it returned null at every cell.

Can you tell me how to detect a tap on a cell within the TableViewController? Complete code attached.

http://pastebin.com/r12Yv9Be

Comment: Have you set delegate and dataSource for tableView?

Comment: Jep, I did set the delegate and dataSource in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and saw that you are adding a tap gesture recognizer to the whole view. It might be that this stops touches from being transferred to the tableview cells. I would try removing that gesture recognizer and then try again if you reach the didSelect function when clicking the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your viewDidLoad method as follows

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: I set the delegate and dataSource right in the Interface Builder.

Comment: try to put a breakpoint and check that method is being triggered or not

Comment: Breakpoint in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method don't get reached if I tap on any cell in this tableView.

Answer (score 1):

If you setted correctly the delegate and datasource of tableView, you should change the function to the following and see if you actually print the row:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      print("Tap detected. Selected indexPath is: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't print anything. I also did set a breakpoint within this function, but never gets called.

Comment: I just checked your code again. Maybe there is a problem when you set the delegate and dataSource. Can you try to set the delegate in viewDidLoad like this: self.mainTableView.delegate = self and also the dataSource? Then check again if you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: I just added this to make sure it is set. No change.

Comment: You can check if you set the cell selectionStyle to .None.